# $e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} \to \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^{2}}}$ and $\sin(\theta) = -\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^{2}}}$ for $\lambda \to \infty$. Then
$$
\cos(\theta) \to 0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sin(\theta) \to -1 \ \ \text{when} \ \ \lambda \to \infty 
$$
Why
$$
e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} \to \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \ \text{when} \ \ \lambda \to \infty
$$

I put a try here but unfortunately it was wrong and I deleted it. And it had taken me a long time to think what I thought.

Comment: Carin: $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ is not "De Moivre's second formula". It is (one of) Euler's formula(s). And it holds for any complex number $\theta$, and so does $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ @Semiclassical

Comment: Your comments won't let them know (so can you please clear them off?). The history of the edits of your post will.

Comment: Carin again can you please clean up this section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^{2}}}$ and $\sin(\theta) = -\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^{2}}}$ with $\lambda \to+\infty$

is equivalent to

$\theta\to-\frac\pi2\bmod{2\pi}$

i.e. to

$\frac\theta2\to-\frac\pi4\bmod\pi$ (not $\bmod{2\pi}$),

i.e. to

$e^{i\frac\theta2}\to\pm\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ (informally), in any case not to $e^{i\frac\theta2}\to\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}2.$

Comment: $\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ mod $2\pi$  if  $\theta +  \frac{\pi}{2}  \to  2k \pi$ ?

Comment: $a\to b\bmod c\iff a-b\to0\bmod c.$ But $a-b$ itself can have no limit.

Comment: $a-b \to 0$ mod c?

Comment: $x\to0\bmod c\iff d(x,c\Bbb Z)\to0.$ E.g. $2\pi n+\frac1n\to0\bmod{2\pi}$ but there is no fixed $k$ such that $2\pi n+\frac1n\to2k\pi.$

Comment: $\cos(\theta) = 0$ then $\theta = \pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. And how $\sin(\theta) = -1$ then $\theta = 2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then  $\theta/2 = \pi n - \frac{\pi}{4}$ such that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, and no need of $\cos,$ and it is an iff, and written more correctly: $\sin\theta=-1\iff$ *there exists* an $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\theta=-\frac\pi2+2\pi n$ (or equivalently $\frac\theta2=-\frac\pi4+\pi n$ i.e. $-\frac\pi4\bmod{2\pi}$ if $n$ even but $+\frac\pi4\bmod{2\pi}$ if $n$ odd). Moreover, here your hypothesis is not $\sin\theta=-1,$ it is $\sin\theta\to-1,$ i.e. $\theta$ varies, and the integer $n$ such that $\theta+\frac\pi2-2\pi n$ gets closer and closer to $0$, this $n$ varies with $\theta$ and may be sometimes even, sometimes odd.

Comment: Thank you very much.